# Windows VSCode intellisense is not working when using a mounted linux drive

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a mounted folder on my windows machine that allows me to access several git repositories on a remote Linux machine. In order to avoid having to run a remote desktop client or some kind of X Session editor, I would like to configure my windows machine such that it feels like I am running VS Code on the same system as the repositories.

I am able to see all of the source code when I open the U: drive on my windows machine, however I am not able to get intellisense working. What do I need to change so that my Windows VS Code instance is able to support intellisense in this way?

```
Linux Machine:
   /disk0/scratch/repos/CC
       repo1/
       repo2/
       repo3/
       ...
```

```
Windows Machine:
   CC (U:)    <---- mounted with Samba
       repo1/
       repo2/
       repo3/
       ...
```

```
VS Code settings.json

{
   ...
   "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "U:\\repo1,
        "U:\\repo2,
        "U:\\repo3,
        ...
   ],
   ...
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant but all of the repos are C/C++. I have the C++/C extension but still nothing is working.

Edit: To clarify - I am not able to get *ANY* intellisense... VS Code does not even suggest keyboards. In the past I have found that if I type a letter, VS Code will immediately open a little scroll panel by the cursor and offer suggestions.

I have been using this broken setup for about a week now and I have noticed that sometimes I am able to `ctrl + click` on a function and it takes me the `hpp` definition and other says it will not even be able to do that.

Comment: VS Code has remote extensions, you may consider looking into the ssh extension. You will be required to have a VS Code server on the remote machine, however.

Comment: But without a better view of how your VS Code is configured, getting help will be difficult.

Comment: @sweenish Wow I did not know that there was already a tool for this. I just installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack and it did all of the configuration for me! Thank you so much!